# How to dismiss a ContentDialog by tapping out site of it in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with ContentDialog, as you knew, a ContentDialog can be dismissed when we tap to its button, but now, I want to dismiss this by tapping to the out site section of it. How to do that? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

When you calling the ShowAsync method of ContentDialog pass the CancellationTokenSource(cts);

```
 CancellationTokenSource cts;
 cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
contentDialog.ShowAsync().AsTask(cts.Token);
```

listen for Tapped event of the page. Cancel the task(ContenDialog task)
 inside event method like below

```
void Page_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           contentDialog.Hide();
            cts.Cancel();

        }
```

Comment: Excuse me, can you detail it?

Comment: Have you tried it, because it return an error to me!
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Comment: did you try calling Hide method of contentdialog without any taskcancellation?

Comment: Mostly exception is because calling Hide after cancelling the task. Try calling Hide() before Cancell(). See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PopUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842) control and its IsOpen property. I hope thats more suitable in your case though the ContentDialog has Hide() method to hide it.

Documented it [here](https://windowsdevblog.wordpress.com/).